# How do I get Skin off my untamed baby leopard gecko?? HELP

Tags: health, reptiles, leopard-geckos, molting

So I got a juvenile leopard gecko named Scout about 3 days ago. I haven't held him yet because I wanted him to get comfortable in his new home before I did that. He had just finished shedding a bit before when we got him, but he still has little "socks" on his toes. I was told to put him in a warm shallow bath, but he's not tamed yet and happens to hate water. what can I do to get it off but not make him uncomfortable??

Answer (score 1):

You can use a damp cotton swab (Q-tip) to gently massage the stuck shed off his toes. The bath would be best to get them soft enough to easily remove. It's important to not let the shed constrict blood flow to the toes as this can result in necrosis. The skin shrinks as it dries, so make sure you check his feet every day to make sure you got all the stuck shed off.